# ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano con esta consulta de postgres?

Tags: postgresql

estoy intentando cargar información de diferentes tablas en una.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
UPDATE coche ch
INNER JOIN modelo mo ON mo.id = ch.codmodelo
INNER JOIN color co ON co.idmodelo = ch.codmodelo
INNER JOIN matricula ma ON ma.idmodelo = ch.codmodelo
SET ch.codmodelo = mo.id, ch.codcolor=co.id, ch.codmatricula=ma.id
WHERE mo.id >0
```

Mi intención es actualizar los campos de la tabla coches, con un campo especifico de las tablas modelo, color y matricula.

Si alguien puede echarme una mano para entender como hacerlo. Lo que he encontrado por internet o preguntado no me ha ayudado a resolverlo.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas deben ir con datos de prueba y resultado esperado. No sabemos si el join que planteas va a arrojar registros o no (puede que el tipo de join sea incorrecto). Por favor, [edit] la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para simular `JOIN` en un `UPDATE` debes utilizar `FROM`, te recomiendo la [documentacion oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE orderlines o set quantity =1, orderdate =current_Date + c.age  
FROM orders as oo, customers  as c  
WHERE
o.orderid = oo.orderid AND 
oo.customerid =c.customerid  AND 
c.country ='US'
```

y en tu caso quedaría algo como esto:

```
UPDATE coche ch
SET codmodelo = mo.id, codcolor=co.id, codmatricula=ma.id

FROM modelo as mo,color as co, matricula as ma 
WHERE
mo.id = ch.codmodelo AND 
co.idmodelo = ch.codmodelo AND
ma.idmodelo = ch.codmodelo AND
mo.id >0
```

Comment: Buenas @Anthony Sotolongo he probado a lanzarlo así. Pero me indica UPDATE 0, como que no se ha actualizado con los valores de las tablas. ¿podria ser por las FK?, tengo una de la tabla color apuntando a modelo y otra desde matricula apuntando a modelo.  Y en la tabla que quiero actualizar "coche" tengo otra fk apuntando a modelo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Entonces no hay match de "JOIN" en esa consulta, puede ser incluso por la condicion del `mo.id >0` , te recomiendo que hagas un `SELECT` simulando esos `JOIN` para ve si retorna algo, y de esas pruebas armas tu `UPDATE`

Comment: Buenos días @Anthony Sotolongo, he conseguido insertar los resultados. Hice el select y me salen los resultados que necesito. He intentado montar el UPDATE pero no soy capaz de hacer que inserte los datos, bueno da UPDATE ROWS 0.. He conseguido hacerlo con un INSERT y dentro el SELECT. A ojos de una persona con mas practica. ¿Lo ves como una chapuza? jaja un saludo y muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Pudiera tal vez lograrse, con mas conocimiento del negocio, pero lo más importante es que buscastes alternativas para solucionarlo, felicidaides por eso